# C# with MS Access Database Error = Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, database, variables, local

here is the code is self, its inside a class

```
 class Class1
{
    public string compute (string no1, string no2)
    {
        string computed;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(no1) - 8 == 0)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(no2) > 0)
            {
                computed = (60 / Convert.ToInt32(no2)).ToString();
            }
            if (Convert.ToUInt32(no2) == 0)
            {
                computed = "0";
            }
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(no1) - 8 != 1)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(no2) > 0)
            {
                computed = ((Convert.ToInt32(no1) - 8) + (60 / Convert.ToInt32(no2)).ToString();
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(no2) == 0)
            {
                computed = ((Convert.ToInt32(no1) - 8)).ToString();
            }
        }
        return computed;
    }
}
```

Ive also tried to use the code directly in the main form but i cant use it on a CommandText,

```
           connect.Open();
           OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
           command.Connection = connect;
           command.CommandText = "update Table1 set ot='"+ computed +"' where Fname = '" + uname+"' ";
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           connect.Close();
           MessageBox.Show("Save Complete");
```

also got the same error.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the `string computed` is never assigned in the case that non of the if statements match.

Comment: You're also missing a `)` at the end of this line `computed = ((Convert.ToInt32(no1) - 8) + (60 / Convert.ToInt32(no2)).ToString();`, just before the semicolon.

Comment: `var computed = string.Empty;` will give it an empty value and the error will go away. Should you throw an error rather than return if nothing is assigned to `computed`?

Comment: What a mess... why work with strings instead of numbers, and then doing Convert.ToInt32 + ToString all over the place? Also, always be careful with integer division, it may produce unexpected results, e.g. 60 / 31 = 1 using `int` math.

Comment: Thank you all. var computed = string.Empty; do the trick. also the missing ). Thank you all again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try: `string computed = String.Empty;`

Comment: Line terminator is missing

Answer (score 0):

Set string computed = String.Empty and use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace to validate the computed string e.g.

```js
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(computed))
            {
                connect.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connect;
                command.CommandText = "update Table1 set ot='" + computed + "' where Fname = '" + uname + "' ";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Save Complete");
            }
```